# reduce padding before headings rmdformats downcute

Tags: r-markdown, rmdformats

Working with the downcute rmdformat and have written some custom css to tweak to my need. However, there are large gaps in the document before each new heading and I can't find while looking at the html. Any padding doesn't seem to be associated with these elements but I must be missing something.

Would be grateful for any hints or tips.